# Tween Max Skew Problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, skew, gsap

My code is below. The `TweenMax` skew doesn't work when I add a second line of code, altering the skew in `waterSkew` function. It works fine when the second line of the `waterSkew` function is removed.

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([TransformMatrixPlugin]);

//CHANTEL Timeline variables
var cMoveTimeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite();

function init():void{

waterSkew();
cMove();
}

function cMove():void{
cMoveTimeline.to(C,2,{x:166.9, y:479.55});
cMoveTimeline.to(C,1,{x:166.9, y:467.7, rotation:5}, "+=.15");
cMoveTimeline.to(C,1,{x:163.3, y:471.25, rotation:-5}, "+=.25");
cMoveTimeline.to(C,1,{x:166.9, y:467.7, rotation:5});
cMoveTimeline.to(C,1,{x:166.9, y:479.55, rotation:-5}, "+=.25");
cMoveTimeline.to(C,1,{x:170.5, y:469.5, rotation:0});
}

function waterSkew():void{
TweenMax.to(water, 8, {transformMatrix:{skewX:1, skewY:-1}});
TweenMax.from(water, 8, {transformMatrix:{skewX:1, skewY:1}});
}
init();
```

Comment: The problem is the second line is overwriting the first. Are you trying to reverse the effect? That code as you have it doesn't do one and then do the other, they will try to execute at the same time.

Comment: there is a TweenMax.fromTo function you can use it